# Endomondo struggling with getting precise GPS data

Tags: location-services

Within the last month or so, I have started to see a decline in accuracy when tracking workouts using Endomondo on my Lumia 950. It takes ages to get a fix and it only follows movements occasionally resulting in loss of tracked distance.

Endomondo has paused development of their Windows Phone app and the current one does not officially support Windows 10, but it has been working fine for about a year now. I have searched for a way to reset the GPS data in Windows to get it back on track, but there don't seem to be a setting for that.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: This seems to happen after an update has been installed. Even though the phone was restarted in the end of the update process, GPS fix seems quite random until another restart has been done.

Comment: When did you last reboot your 950? I've seen issues with mine in getting a GPS fix for tracking (when using the driving directions), or sometimes tracking my 40-50m off into a field

Comment: @RowlandShaw: This is embarrassing!! I was sure that I already did a restart, but decided to make sure after your comment. And that of cause fixed the problem, so thank you for this very simple answer!

Comment: I only found that out after much annoyance of being taken down a single track road when I was leading a convoy, with lots of oncoming traffic

Comment: Mee too, and in Maps as well. Without WIFI I often need to let the phone searching for signal on the night before so that in the next morning I have it ready... :/ (mine is not a reboot issue..)